# Polling SQS from Step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I have two AWS Glue jobs in my application.

The first glue job produced some data and it passes to a lambda and lambda errors goes into a DLQ (SQS)

If there is no error messages in DLQ, I want to run the second Glue job.

I want to automate this logic with Step function. So the steps of step function will be:

1. run first glue job.
2. poll DLQ
3. if DLQ has no message for some time, run second glue job.

Is there any way to poll SQS for messages from step function ?

Answer (score 1):

**Answering the main question:**  <s>SFN cannot poll SQS directly.  If you really need this kind of integration, SFN can invoke a Lambda to poll a queue and return the result back to your SFN.</s>

[Edit: The recently introduced [Step Function Service Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html) now allow calling the SQS SDK `ReceiveMessage` and `DeleteMessage` APIs on a Queue as a Step Function task.  Although SQS polling is now available in SFN, Queues are arguably not the best fit for the scenario in the OP].

More generally, it's not a typical pattern to use queues as part of a StepFunction architecture.  SFN orchestration is really an *alternative to* queue-based orchestration.  SFN's core function is to [orchestrate tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-states.html) and it has its own [try-catch-error handling logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html). Not that it can't be done with queues, just not sure what the benefit is.

A typical SFN integration pattern starts with an EventBridge cron that triggers a SFN execution. Glue Job 1 is the first task - SFN calls Glue's `StartJobRun` as a [sync-type task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-glue.html) and waits for the result.  Chain together multiple lambda, glue event stages.  Add Error branches to handle failure states.  The job would end with a notification task.

Comment: Hi @fedonev, thanks for answering.
A follow up question, is there a way to poll SQS from lambda ?
Any related article is highly appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help.  Yes.  Using [SQS as a lambda event source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) is a very common serverless pattern.