# Step function step is not failing even when lambda is throwing exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a AWS step function workflow of two steps in sequential manner. In each step, I am calling a lambda.

My first lambda is throwing exception after doing some processing. But overall, my step function workflow is executing completely and it is passing.

Am I missing something in step function configuration ? Ideally I want my step function to stop exception as soon as any step is failing (i.e. lambda of that step is failing).

My step function configuration is below:

```json
    {
      "StartAt": "firstStep",
      "States": {
        "firstStep": {
          "Next": "secondStep",
          "Retry": [
            {
              "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
              ],
              "MaxAttempts": 1,
              "BackoffRate": 1
            }
          ],
          "Type": "Task",
          "OutputPath": "$",
          "ResultPath": "$.Result",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
          "Parameters": {
            "FunctionName": "<some function arn>",
            "Payload": {},
            "InvocationType": "Event"
          }
        },
        "secondStep": {
          "End": true,
          "Retry": [
            {
              "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
              ],
              "MaxAttempts": 1,
              "BackoffRate": 1
            }
          ],
          "Type": "Task",
          "OutputPath": "$",
          "ResultPath": "$.Result",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
          "Parameters": {
            "FunctionName": "<some function arn>",
            "Payload": {},
            "InvocationType": "Event"
          }
        }
      },
      "TimeoutSeconds": 10800
    }
```

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your current definitions tells Step Functions to retry the Lambdas once.   If you wish to fail immediately, either set `MaxAttempts: 0` or remove the (optional) `Retry` block entirely.

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html): *"By default, when a state reports an error, AWS Step Functions causes the execution to fail entirely."*

Also worth noting that if you are catching errors in the Lambda, the Lambda won't report the error.

Comment: @SushilVerma   Problem solved?  If so, please accept the answer.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100265/polling-sqs-from-step-function), too.  Thanks.